# How to have vbs launch a program as administrator?

Tags: vbscript

The end of my VBScript (the rest is mainly `WScript.Echo` reminders) looks like this (launches X-Plane, maximized):

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""X:\X-Plane\X-Plane.exe"""), 3
Set objShell = Nothing
```

What would I need to add to this to get X-Plane to run as administrator? An hour's Googling has got me nowhere!

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have UAC enabled and your user is a member of the Administrators group you can use the [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745.aspx) method with the "runas" verb:

```
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
app.ShellExecute "X:\X-Plane\X-Plane.exe", , , "runas", 3
```

Comment: Thanks - I had found the 'runas' addition, but had assumed there were other parameters to add. I'll try this. :-)

Comment: Oh, I do not have UAC enabled on this PC. Does that mean this will not work?

Comment: Does your account have admin privileges? Or do you need to run the program under a different account? In case of the latter: how do you intend to provide credentials?

Comment: "Does your account have admin privileges?"  Yes, it does.