# I want to use Excel(run as administrator) as Getobject. (vbscript)

Tags: excel, vbscript, administrator

After run excel as administrator, I can't `getobject(, "excell.application")`. -> Error occurred.

Is there has another method which I can control Excel(run as administrator)?

Below is the code I wrote.

```
dim xl_ap, xl, wbs

set xl_ap = createobject("Excel.application")

set xl = getobject(, "excel.application")

for each wbs in xl.workbooks

 set wb = wbs

next

msgbox(wb.name)
```

Comment: You use createobject or getobject(filename) or getobject(,RunningAppName). Not two of them.

Comment: You'll have to run you script as administrator as well to be able to use the Excel instance running as administrator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642201/i-would-like-to-create-a-vbs-file-that-runs-the-xlsm-file-with-administrator-p?answertab=active#tab-top